# Bash: how to look for the next positional parameter in "case" code without hard-coding its value?

Tags: bash, switch-statement

Given the "case" code snippet:

```
case $3 in 
        -a) 
            if [ "$4" == #some regex to match pattern ]; then
                #do some additional work
            else
                #proceed as usual
            fi
            ;;
```

How could I better express my intention to look for a positional parameter which is located right next on the right-hand side of the current position $3 (or $3++, if that makes sense), instead of hard-coding it to $4 in the "if" statement?

EDIT:

the simplest usage of my script would look like this:

```
./script.sh company region -a LIST-123
```

the first two mandatory positional arguments (company & region) are fixed.
Starting from the position $3, users have to provide at least one mandatory argument in the format of a preceding dash and a single letter (-a, -b, -c etc).
The single-letter mandatory arguments can have an optional argument (LIST-123 in the example above). If the optional argument is not provided, the script should resume as usual.

I want users to be able provide multiple mandatory-optional argument pairs. like this:

```
./script.sh company region -a LIST-123 -b LIST-456 -c LIST-789
```

Also, to have flexibility to provide the mandatory single-letter args in any order:

```
./script.sh company region -c LIST-789 -b LIST-456 -a LIST-123
```

And to be able to provide optional arguments only to certain mandatory single-letter args, but not all:

./script.sh company region -c LIST-789 -b -a LIST-123

Comment: please elaborate more about what you're doing.

Comment: You probably want to look at the `getopts` command, to avoid hard-coding `$3` in the first place.

Comment: @kamokoba `shift` is the one you're looking for.  see `help shift`

Comment: If you're writing an option/argument parser the `mandatory` can be process with an option as well. see my example code.

Answer (score 2):

Here an example of using shift.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while (($#)); do
  case $1 in
    country) echo "$1" is given
      ;;
    region) echo "$1" is given
      ;;
    -a)
      printf 'Current first parameter is: %s\n' "$1"
      shift
      printf '%s %s\n' "Next to -a is" "$1";;
    -b)
      printf 'Current first parameter is: %s\n' "$1"
      shift
      printf '%s %s\n' "Next to -b is" "$1"
      ;;
    *)
      printf '%s\n' "Unknown option $1" >&2
      exit 1
  esac
  shift
done
```

Now run the script with the following option and arguments.

```
./myscript country region -b bar -a foo
```

output

```
country is given
region is given
Current first parameter is: -b
Next to -b is bar
Current first parameter is: -a
Next to -a is foo
```

- I gave you the base solution, you just need to adapt it to your needs.
- Like I said the `mandatory` can be with option too, so regardless where it end up in the arguments (first, middle, last) It can be process properly.

Comment: this won't work with shift --> ./script.sh foo bar -a word -b word. Shift will shift out -b and its value will be lost. Only the first part will be working ok ("-a word")

Comment: I thought you will never ask..., I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

`shift` is exactly what you're looking for.  See `help shift`:

```
shift: shift [n]
Shift positional parameters.

Rename the positional parameters $N+1,$N+2 ... to $1,$2 ...  If N is
not given, it is assumed to be 1.

Exit Status:
Returns success unless N is negative or greater than $#.
```

Your (working!) code could look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

case $3 in
    -a)
    shift
        if [ "$3" == "word" ];
    then
        echo it matches
            #do some additional work
    else
        echo it does not match
            #proceed as usual
        fi
    ;;
esac
```

You could also use `eval` although it's [not
recommended](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332579/is-it-always-safe-to-use-eval-echo):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

case $3 in
    -a)
        if [ "$(eval echo \$$((3+1)))" == "word" ]; 
    then
        echo it matches
            #do some additional work
    else
        echo it does not match
            #proceed as usual
        fi
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, appreciate your time. Perhaps I had to be more specific in describing what I wanted to achieve with my script (done it now). Basically, there might be cases where there are more than one optional parameter provided. Given your version of "case" code, if the same logic was implemented for parameter "-b" as for "-a" (even adjusting positional param value in "if" block), the code would work only for "-a", while the "-b" code would be ignored (I did test it). That's probably because the parameter is being shifted out and its value lost after the first execution

Comment: OK. So is your issue solved now or do you have some more questions?

Comment: as I said, this won't work with shift --> ./script.sh foo bar -a word -b word

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
case $3:$4 in 
     -a:[a-z]*) echo ok ;;
```

Or

```
case $3:$4 in
     -a:[Tt]est) echo ok ;;
```